# How to make PowerShell $ie COM object reference new browser window

Tags: html, powershell

I have a powershell script which logs in to a site and clicks on a link leading to an external site. When the link is clicked it opens in a new window and closes the original window.

This is an issue because I need to get access to the elements on the new page but am unable to perform any commands (such as getElementById) on the document because the $ie com object is still referencing the original window. Is there a way to tell the $ie com object to reference the new window that opens rather than the old window? any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Created a new InternetExplorer.Application COM object, like so

```
$ie2 = New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application

$ie2.Navigate("linkToPopupWindow.com")
```

I was then able to reference the document object of $ie2 after performing a sleep, like so:

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
$doc = $ie2.Document
```

This worked for me. Thanks for everyone's input. Hopefully this helps someone else. If anyone is struggling similarly, feel free to message me and I can try and help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to the correct IE instance.

```
$AllExplorers = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows()
```

This will return all File and Internet explorer objects.

Next you can find your IE either by Name or URL.

```
$MyIE = $AllExplorers | Where-Object {$_.LocationName -eq "Google"}}
$MyIE = $AllExplorers | Where-Object {$_.LocationUrl -like "*google.com*"}
```

You can now search `$MyIE` for elements...

```
$element = $MyIE.Document.getElementById('ID')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried this and received this error message: "An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Access is denied. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))."

Comment: I am using IE com object, not shell: Code looks like so: 
$AllExplorers = (New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application).Windows()
[NEWLINE] $AllExplorers

Comment: UPDATE: I made the $AllExplorers variable an array, which solved my last error. However now I receive this new error: Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a 
method named 'Windows'.

Comment: I'm trying to use "Shell.Application" rather than "InternetExplorer.Application", in order to access the ".Windows()" property but getting errors as well. Is there a way to access the Windows()  via InternetExplorer.Application object?

Comment: @Quanda what version of PS are you running? Are you running in STA? (Single threaded apartment) some COM component need that.

Comment: PowerShell 4.0. How do I know if I am running STA? @Jan Chrbolka

Comment: If you running PS 4 you should be fine, it runs in STA by default. I would suggest to go back to the code in the answer and try to get rid of the COM error.  Run as Administrator?